# Reference zoo variable names after lag, hyphen confused with subtraction

Tags: r, zoo

After using the lag function on a multi variable zoo object, new variables are created with an automatic naming convention that uses a hyphen. For example, lags of the variable `var2` will be named as `var2.lag-4` and so on. The problem is that when I want to refer to this variable, such as in `plot(var2.lag-4)` it returns the error message  object `var2.lag` not found

I presume this is because it sees the hyphen sign as a subtraction sign between one variable name and the scalar number 4.

Is it possible to refer to these lagged zoo variables without this error?

Note that I have also attached the object, so that variable names can be used directly.

Here is an example

```
var1 = ts(rnorm(20), start=1995.00, freq=4)
var2 = ts(rnorm(20), start=1995.00, freq=4)
X = cbind(var1, var2) 
newX = lag(as.zoo(X),-1:-4) # lags 1 to 4 of all variables
attach(as.list(newX))
plot(var2.lag-1) 
#Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
#In addition: Warning messages:
#1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
#2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
#3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `k` has names, those will be used to create the new column names. So you could add names to the vector you pass to `k`:

```
k <- -1:-4
# make.names will ensure the column names are syntactically valid
names(k) <- make.names(paste0("lag",k))
newX <- lag(as.zoo(X), k)
```

And `plot` doesn't know what to do with character strings. You have to pass it an object to plot.

```
plot(newX$var2.lag.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell `plot` that the string is a name of a column of `newX`:

```
plot(newX[ , "var2.lag-1"])
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry one thing I forgot to say was that I also attached the object, so that directly referencing the variable names should be allowed. I have edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: My advice is to never use `attach`. But if you do, you need to use backticks instead of quotes in `plot` to reference a variable with a non-standard name.